# JavaScript page bruteforcer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, brute-force

I have written a very simple script to test one page for possible discounts options.
But I have faced the problem that once I do 'button.click();' the page loading is blocked until I complete my function, so following actions like button.click(); do not make sense.

Is that possible to make page to load while I am inside of the function? This should be ran in Developer toolbar in safari (I believe I cannot set onload event for the page on my side, so need to do that without using even handlers).

```
    var card = document.getElementById('discount_card');
    var button = $('.buttonTotal');
    var disc_val = document.getElementById('cart_discount').firstChild;
    for(var i=init;i<=finish;i++){
        card.value = i;
        button.click();
        disc = disc_val.data;
        if(disc > my_discount) console.log(disc + " : " + i);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you mixin js and jQuery? If you're using jQuery you'd be better grabbing elements with it.

Comment: I know that the page is using jQuery, although I am not very familiar with it. If you can tell me how to do that, I would appreciate that!

Comment: I mean `document.getElementById('discount_card')` replace with `$('#discount_card')` and `document.getElementById('cart_discount').firstChild` with `$('#cart_discount').first()`. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Does order of buttons clicking matters? If no, try to replace `button.click();` with `(function (button) {setTimeout(function () {button.click();}, 1)})(button);`

If order matters, you still can use setTimeout, but you'll be needed to change your script logic (replace loop with recursion).

Comment: I have tried that in the Developer console, seems not to work.. 


var discountCheck=function(id){
        var card = document.getElementById('discount_card');
        var button = $('.buttonTotal');
        var disc_val = document.getElementById('cart_discount').firstChild;
        card.value = id;
        (function (button) {setTimeout(function () {button.click();}, 1)})(button);
        return disc_val.data;
 
        
};

Comment: I have called that as discountCheck(12312); and expected to get 7.0 (percentage of discount) but have gotten a 0, since the part of page was updated in some quick time with discount value. And when I called the function the second time - have gotten 7% value. That is my problem described in the first message, I need the function to wait until value is updated and do not block page loading.

Comment: Is that possible at all or JS is always blocking?

Comment: not working, the problem is that we are making the pause before button click this way.. but we need to do this after the click and at the same time not to block running ajax which checks discount for the card number and updates cart_discount value. I have tried to make it work as a pair of functions, but I am confused with timers in js - this work not as I expect.. Is that possible to prevent blocking content during pause?

Comment: Javascript executes in one thread. When it executes, it also blocks UI thread, thus the page freezes. To give UI thread a bit CPU time to execute, setTimeout is used.